# Application pool disabling

Tags: iis, application-pool

I have an application in the Production environment which is Windows Server 2012/IIS 8 and is load balanced.

Recently out of nowhere, the website app pool suddenly started gettig disabled. The System Windows Logs logged the following error message by the Resource-Exhaustion-Detector ...

Application Pool 'x' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: w3wp.exe (6604) consumed 5080641536 bytes, w3wp.exe (1572) consumed 477335552 bytes, and w3wp.exe (352) consumed 431423488 bytes.

Anyone got any idea how I figure out what is happening? We've never come across this issue before and the application has been running for a good couple of years.

Also, this isn't something that happens regularly but instead seems to happen one every day or so, and even that is at a random time. The Virtual Memory was initially 4GB but because of the issue above, we increased it to 8GB. Recently it spiked at using about 6.8GB out of 8GB, which it has no reason to do so.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Memory leak... See http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-native-memory-leak-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

Comment: solved the problem?

Answer (score -1):

### The answer is easy here, obviously and certainly you have two issues here

1- You have a serious bug in your process/code that happens intermittently "you need to debug it to find how/when that happens" or at least run a [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) 
such that you keep it listening on the server on the process W3WP till an exception happens and then analyze this dump to find where the code get stuck and consume that memory/otherwise just debug the code and see what changes were made in last few months "not days"

2- the application get stopped because you have configured/it is configured by default to get disabled break after a certain number of failure repeats, and that's a normal behavior but the main issue as I said is not the application pool itself, its inside the process

please let me know if you need a further explanation or help on this matter